# Why can't I store these coordinates in a JS array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have these images:

```html
  <div id="dvSource">
    <img id="image0" img alt="image0" src="upload/<?php echo $user_id; ?>/0" />
    <img id="image1" img alt="image1" src="upload/<?php echo $user_id; ?>/1" />
    </br>
    <img id="image2" img alt="image2" src="upload/<?php echo $user_id; ?>/2" />
    <img id="image3" img alt="image3" src="upload/<?php echo $user_id; ?>/3" />
</div>
```

and they can be moved into other divs using some JavaScript I have. I am trying to store their coordinates in an array but it isn't working, this is what I've got:

```js
var pos = $('#image0').position();
pos.top;
pos.left;
var pos1 = $('#image1').position();
pos.top;
pos.left;
var pos2 = $('#image2').position();
pos.top; 
pos.left; 
var pos3 = $('#image3').position();
pos.top;  
pos.left; 

var positions = ["1", "2", "3"];
document.getElementById("coordinatesjs").value = var positions;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post [mcve] without PHP - show the RENDERED HTML and script

Comment: a lot of thing...
first - don't use `var` in a right side operand...
second - you're not really saving anything..

Comment: `value = var positions` is not valid JS and `pos.top;
pos.left;` does nothing

Comment: What are the lines `pos.top;
pos.left;
` supposed to do? They don't do anything. It's not clear what you think you're doing.

Comment: …and even if `#coordinatesjs` is an input (other elements don't have a `value`) you can't set an array to it, without serializing the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What am I doing wrong?

Primarily, four things:

1. You're not putting the positions in an array, you're just getting them and then throwing them away:

   ```
   var pos = $('#image0').position();
   pos.top;
   pos.left;
   ```
2. Your syntax later, `var positions = ["1", "2", "3"];`, is indeed the correct way to create an array directly, but that array just contains the strings `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"`, nothing to do with the `pos` (or `pos1`, etc.) variables earlier.

   You can combine that syntax with getting the positions, like this:

   ```
   var positions = [
       $('#image0').position(),
       $('#image1').position(),
       $('#image2').position(),
       $('#image3').position()
   ];
   ```

   However, you're probably better off doing it dynamically, but finding the `img` elements in your `#dvSource` element:

   ```
   var positions = $("#dvSource img").map(function() {
       return $(this).position();
   }).get();
   ```

   That uses [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get a jQuery object containing the position objects, and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get a real array for it.
3. You don't need to use `var` before every time you use a variable, so this line of code is a syntax error:

   ```
   document.getElementById("coordinatesjs").value = var positions;
   // Here -----------------------------------------^
   ```

   Just remove that `var`. But see #4.
4. When you assign an array of objects to the `value` property of an `input`, you won't get anything useful, just `"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"`. You need to format those values in some way. Here's an example formatting them as valid JSON (a textual notation for data exchange):

   ```
   document.getElementById("coordinatesjs").value = JSON.stringify(positions);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

1. `= var positions`is not valid JS
2. `<br/>` not `</br>`
3. You did not actually store anything anywhere

Here is some code that actually does something

```js
var positions = [];
$(".img").each(function() {
  positions.push($(this).position()); // or push({ "top":position.top,"left":position.left});
})  
$("#coordinatesjs").html(
  JSON.stringify(positions) // convert to string
  .replace(/},/g,"}<br/>")  // replace }, with <br/>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvSource">
    <img id="image0" class="img" alt="image0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=0" />
    <img id="image1" class="img" alt="image1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=0" />
    <br />
    <img id="image2" class="img" alt="image2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=0" />
    <img id="image3" class="img" alt="image3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=0" />
</div>

<div id="coordinatesjs"></div>
```